# Auto-generate puppet manifests?

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to auto-generate Puppet manifests from an existing system?

For example, if we need to deploy a site to a pre-configured VPS or shared server, is there a tool which could query a server then generate puppet manifests to mirror what it found? (distro, app versions, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use puppet resource [type] for that, but be selective. You don't want a huge manifest, just manage what is important.

To get a list of installed packages:

```
puppet resource package
```

Get a specific package with version:

```
puppet resource package httpd
```

Files:

```
puppet resource file /etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf
```

Comment: for anyone else new to Puppet, 'pacakage' is a type, not a placeholder. Here's the list of Puppet resource types: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with say, apache2? Can it get all the vhosts and apache mods along with it?